# Private Endpoints in a Hub and Spoke

Tags: azure, networking, routes

I am working on Azure architecture using a hub-spoke model. I've come across an issue where I'm unable to access a storage account (connected via private endpoint) from a VM located in a different virtual network through the Azure portal.

Setup:

Hub-Spoke Architecture
Azure Firewall deployed in the hub
3 Virtual Networks:
Contains a Firewall,
Contains a Virtual Machine,
Contains a Private Endpoint attached to an Azure Storage Account

Configuration:

All private DNS zones are created and linked to the hub network.
Conditional forwarding is set on the firewall for the private zones to contact Azure DNS.
Route tables are in place on each subnet directing traffic through the firewall.
Able to resolve the private IP of the storage account from the VM.
Issue:
Despite the above configuration, when I try to access the storage account containers from the VM through the Azure portal, I get a message asking to add my public IP to the allow list in the network settings of the storage account.

Is there something I'm missing or a configuration that I need to tweak to get this to work? Your insights would be greatly appreciated. Attached is a diagram for reference.

[image]

Comment: In storage account add your selected virtual network and Ip addresses and add exiting vnet of your vm with client Ip address and save like [this](https://i.imgur.com/pzB7hTD.png)

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is how I have it set up as a workaround at the moment. My main concern is that some of the traffic to the Storage Account will bypass the virtual firewall appliance.

Comment: By doing this, all traffic to the VM will be forced to go through the virtual firewall appliance, including traffic to the storage account. This will ensure that all traffic is inspected by the virtual firewall appliance before being allowed to pass through to the storage account.

Comment: I tested the NSG, however, it still gives me the error for the firewall. I added an inbound rule to allow the Virtual Firewall Appliances private IP to anything on the network as a test. I associated the NSG to both subnets for the VM and the Private Endpoint for the Storage Account.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the NSG is needed if I have a Route Table forcing the next hop for all traffic to the Virtual Network Appliance. Should the Firewall rules on the Virtual Firewall appliance not take precedence? Furthermore when attempting to access the storage account with public access completely disabled the firewall error message on the storage account states we need to add the public IP of the Firewall to the allow list. So it doesn't seem to be recognizing the private IP of the Firewall.

Comment: it's possible that the storage account is not recognizing the private IP of the virtual firewall appliance due to a misconfiguration or issue with the private endpoint connection having route table nsg is not necessary only. check the private endpoint connection is approved, check DNS configuration for the virtual network and storage account, private DNS zone is linked to the virtual network and that the virtual network is configured to use the private DNS zone. check virtual network and the private IP address of the virtual firewall appliance are added to the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a message asking to add my public IP to the allow list in the
> network settings of the storage account.

This error usually occurs, while configuring private links to your storage account from private endpoints on virtual network subnets where the clients reside that require access to your data.

You need to add your public IP to the allow list in the network so that storage account is configured to only allow traffic from specific IP addresses.

***In storage account -> networking -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> Add existing virtual network -> Specify the virtual network subnet like below:***

[image]

Specify the client public IP address ranges, such as those on on-premises networks, from which you want to grant access and add exceptions to allow access from trusted services required for operations such as backing up data.

[image]

Network rules are implemented for all requests after being applied.  SAS tokens that grant access to a specific IP address serve to limit the access of the token.

***Reference***:

[Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal)

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram shows a Virtual Network Link from the Private DNS Zone to the Hub Network. This may be needed, but what is missing is a Virtual Network Link from the Private DNS Zone to Spoke Two in case you are using Azure DNS. DNS resolution is done on the VM using DNS configured for the VNet. Without linking the Private DNS Zone to Spoke Two the public IP will be returned and you need the mentioned firewall settings to access the storage account.